# ActiveMerchant::ConnectionError with NelixTransax TransaxGateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I've tried the example usage from [here](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant#usage) (in the rails console) and it works fine, but when I try using it with this changed (to what Nelix's demo has for credentials) it does not work. All I get is a ConnectionError (after a long time).

```
gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::TransaxGateway.new(
            :login => 'demo',
            :password => 'password')
```

When I browse to their test_url (which is the same as their live_url) it comes back right away.  How can I get this working?  Any tips for debugging this would also be appreciated. [I've tried it with Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 under rails 3.2.13.]

Comment: Have you found the solution? I'm testing with `BraintreeGateway` and have the same error. A vague `ActiveMerchant::ConnectionError`

Comment: No solution was found.  We went with Authorize.NET and have not had any problems.